# Send to client that's interpreted as a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

From a Ajax response (coming from the server) that does not go through JSON (does not use JSON) am I able to send a string to the client that can be interpreted as a JavaScript Object and executed?

I'm sorry, I'm having a mental block: I'm not sure what I should send to a JavaScript front end (client) after a user authentication on the server. I know that there needs to be some controls for the user (user/admin)to click but I'm not sure what to send that's secure and what not to send that's not secure. I've been told hidden controls are not secure. I know how to implement user authentication on the server. I understand a check on the server needs to be made if a control is clicked to check if the user (user/admin) has the right permissions for that control before the server executes the control function (on the server). I know I can set a variable and send it to the front end, once it's received (Ajax response) add controls (appendChild). If I do it this way, I feel it's not secure because all the code to do this is easily viewable by the browser (page source).

Comment: What do you mean by executed?

Comment: If your string is formatted as JSON, then `JSON.parse(str)` will give you a javascript object.

Comment: *Executed* ? What you mean by executed? So you're returning to your website a string (of what?  a word? a function? a variable? a...? ) XY question? what you need to accomplish? Any code to share?

Answer (score -4):

You can use eval() function. But why send string?

Comment: 1. the question is not clear at all. 2. eval() is a form of evil (for many good reasons! 3. what's wrong with window["objAsString"] (again, the Q is not clear enough to give any answer at all)

Comment: I believe you have enough rep to post comments, so if you want to ask for additional information such as your *why send string* question, it would be better as a comment on the question.

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake, I should clarify this in my answer.